# NSManagedObjectContext returning nil iphone

Tags: iphone

I created a class ServerModel for my app and in it I want to make a connection to the Sqlite database I have on the device, but anytime I go to check my NSManagedObjectContext it is returning null.

While the same work well in my other class RootViewController

In my appdelegate I am doing

```
 rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

 serverModel.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the appalication.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}


/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created by merging all of the models found in the application bundle.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
    return managedObjectModel;
}


/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Data.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code that (1) sets up your managed object model (2) sets up your persistent store coordinator and (3) sets up your managed object context?

Comment: Don't post answers to your question to add more information. Edit your original post instead.

Comment: sorry i missed that I can edit my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Data.sqlite"]];
```

What is the value of `storeUrl` after this line is executed? i.e. are you certain that Data.sqlite exists in your application's Documents directory?

Does all this code exist in your application delegate? If you set a breakpoint at the top of your `managedObjectContext` method, does the breakpoint get hit? After it gets hit, and you step through the code, which line is failing?

Comment: Yes the manaedObjectContent breakpoint is being hit

none of the lines are failing

storeUrl value is correct because in rootViewController the table is being filled correctly from the sqlite

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you say that "anytime I go to check my NSManagedObjectContext it is returning null" (although I think you mean `nil`). Do you mean `managedObjectContext` is nil inside your `rootViewController` or inside your application delegate?

Comment: It's nil inside my ServerModel class

Comment: For the line "serverModel.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;", is `serverModel` nil? Also, can you post the `@property` line of code for `managedObjectContext` in your server model class?

Comment: yes that is correct it is nil inside ServerModel 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line "serverModel.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;". Is `serverModel` nil?